# Notifying BindingContext of a new element in a ViewModel

Tags: c#, mvvm, maui

I'm trying to use the `INotifyPropertyChanged` to notify a BindingContext that a new element has been added to the ListView and it should refresh.

Currently I can't get it to work so I'm just setting the BindingContext to null and again to my VM but it doesn't feel right so maybe someone can recommend something.
Page:

```cs
public partial class TurnGuide : ContentPage
{
    public List<StepTree> Turns { get; set; }
    public StepsViewModel Steps { get; set; }

    public TurnGuide()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Steps = new StepsViewModel();
        BindingContext = Steps;
    }

    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        Turns = await this.LoadTurns();
    }

    public async Task<List<StepTree>> LoadTurns()
    {
        ...
    }

    public void StartTurnButton_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var initialSteps = Turns.Take(2);

        foreach (var step in initialSteps)
        {
            Steps.AddLabel(step.label);
        }

        BindingContext = null;
        BindingContext = Steps;
    }
}
```

View Model

```cs
public class StepsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public IList<Step> _Steps { get; set; }

    public IList<Step> Steps {
        get
        {
            return _Steps;
        }
        set
        {
            _Steps = value;
            // Doesn't work yet so the TurnGuide.xaml.cs:BindingContext = null takes place instead
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Steps)));
        }
    }

    public StepsViewModel()
    {
        Steps = new List<Step>();

        Step item = new Step
        {
            Type = "label",
            Text = "Test prompt"
        };
        Steps.Add(item);
    }

    public void AddLabel(string text)
    {
        Steps.Add(new Step { Type = "label", Text = text });
    }
}
```

XAML

```xml
<StackLayout>
    <Button
        Text="Start"
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        VerticalOptions="Center"
        Clicked="StartTurnButton_Clicked" />
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Steps}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Text}" />
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

Mostly I'm not sure if I can just call the `PropertyChanged?.Invoke(...)` in a list like I do and if I can then I'm not sure what's the problem with the binding not refreshing after triggering the StartTurnButton_Clicked event.

Comment: use `ObservableCollection` instead of `List` and it will do this automatically

Comment: The collection should implement the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface and `ObservableCollection<T>` does implement it (and the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you want to the UI fresh itself after adding some items to the `ItemsSource` of ListView, you can use an `ObservableCollection<T>` class for these items. `ObservableCollection<T>` implements the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface, and ListView will install a handler for the `CollectionChanged` event.
Based on your code, I did a test on my side, it works on my side.

You can refer to the following code:

**StepsViewModel.cs**

```
public class StepsViewModel//: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    //public IList<Step> _Steps { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Step> Steps { get; set; }

    public StepsViewModel()
    {
        //Steps = new List<Step>();
        Steps = new ObservableCollection<Step>();

        Step item = new Step
        {
            Type = "label",
            Text = "Test prompt"
        };
        Steps.Add(item);
    }

    public void AddLabel(string text)
    {
        Steps.Add(new Step { Type = "label", Text = text });
    }
}
```

**TurnGuide.xaml.cs**

```
    public async Task<List<StepTree>> LoadTurns()
    {
        List<StepTree> stepTrees = new List<StepTree>();

        stepTrees.Add(new StepTree {  label = "test1"});
        stepTrees.Add(new StepTree {  label = "test2"});
        stepTrees.Add(new StepTree {  label = "test3"});

        return stepTrees;
    }

    public void StartTurnButton_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var initialSteps = Turns.Take(2);

        foreach (var step in initialSteps)
        {
            Steps.AddLabel(step.label);
        }

        //BindingContext = null;
        //BindingContext = Steps;
    }
```

**Note:**

1.If we use an `ObservableCollection<T>` class for these `ItemsSource`, then we don't need to change the `BindingContext` after adding new or deleting items from the `ItemsSource` of ListView(yours is `Steps`), the UI will refresh itself. Here, we don't need to implement interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` for `StepsViewModel.cs`

2.Of course, if properties of the items themselves change during runtime, then the items in the collection should implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and signal changes to property values using the `PropertyChanged` event.

For more information, please check document: [Data binding basics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/xaml/fundamentals/data-binding-basics?view=net-maui-8.0).